# Hide android icon from application list

Tags: android, icons, show-hide

I want to hide my application icon from launcher screen and from Application list as well.
I can hide application icon from launcher using:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);`
```

How can i hide icon from application list as well ???
Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to hide application from list